# What exactly is the relation between the versions of npm and node when installing them with nvm

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

**tl;dr**

Is there is a reason that I shouldn't do the following; Install and manage packages with a version of npm that is different (much newer) from the npm version that comes with the node version I am going to be using to run my app.

**longer**

Some context why I am asking. I have to work with a service that supports only node **0.10.32** (I know, don't ask) and an app that was written some time ago. We need to add some functionality and unfortunately when I try to run the codebase locally it does not because some dependency of some dependency updated the minor version and they introduced *const* or fat arrow notation (=>). We *had* used shrinkwrap to lock down the versions but something must have slipped.

I have spent days on this and at some point it came to me that the problem lies with the package manager not doing what I want. So I managed to install the packages I wanted and shrinkwrapped it using **npm@3.10.10** which is what I get when I use **node@6.12.3** (`nvm use 6.12.3`). And when I want to run the app I just switch to the **node@0.10.32** to make sure that is going to work on the service.

Can anyone think of any problems with this solution or a reason I shouldn't do that?

**Side question**

I noticed that when installing **node** versions using **nvm**, they usually come with a specific version of **npm**? What is the relation of those versions? How are they decided? Was it the latest **npm** version along with that **node** version when it was released? Is it the latest version of **npm** that can run with that specific version of **node**?

Comment: You're saying that the packages you wanted + shrinkwrapping only worked with `npm@3` and don't work with the npm version that comes with node@0.10? (probably `npm@2`)

Comment: @Explosion-Pills I think so. Basically the shrinkwrap I managed to do with npm@3 in a clean installation installs the paclages I want and nothing else where as with npm@2 some packages get installed that I didn't specify (usually having notation not supported by node@0.10) i.e. request-promise will install request 2.83 inside it but I already have request 2.81 in the top (and request-promise just wants request ^2.34.0 when npm@2 but will just use the one on the top and not install anything inside it when npm@3